# Why is my Javascript alert not being displayed?

Tags: php, javascript, alert

Basically, I am trying to call a Javascript alert via PHP. Although, the alert does not work at all.

This is my echo statement that dynamically creates the alert

```
echo "<script>alert('Uploaded file was not in the correct format\n\nExample of the correct format:\nquestion1,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4\n
question2,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4\nquestion3,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4')</script>";
```

I found that if I change the alert to this, it works perfectly:

```
echo "<script>alert('Uploaded file was not in the correct format')</script>";
```

I believe there is a problem with the linebreaks.

I changed my code to this, yet still no luck:

```
echo "<script>alert('Uploaded file was not in the correct format\\nExample of the correct format:\\nquestion1,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4\\n
question2,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4\\nquestion3,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4')</script>";
```

I am getting an error of:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
[Break On This Error]   

alert('Uploaded file was not in the correct format\nExample of the
------^

createplay.php (line 1, col 6)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to why this is not working? Searched online far and wide and could not find a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using `\\n` instead of `\n`

Comment: Why are you looking at your PHP and declaring that your JavaScript isn't working? Look at the generated JavaScript!

Comment: What happens if you swap the quote styles? `echo '<script>alert("Uploaded file was not in the correct format\n\nExample of the correct format:\nquestion1,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4\n
question2,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4\nquestion3,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4")</script>';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\n` characters are being replaced by literal line breaks by PHP.

Am unescaped literal line break inside a string literal is an error in JavaScript.

Use `\\n` to send a line break escape sequence to JavaScript.

Comment: I changed my `echo` to this, yet is still refuses to work `echo "<script>alert('Uploaded file was not in the correct format\\nExample of the correct format:\\nquestion1,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4\\n
question2,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4\\nquestion3,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4')</script>";`

Comment: What does the generated JS look like? What does the JS console say?

Comment: Used your solution and switched around the quotes like the others stated. Worked perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

```
    <?
    echo "<script>alert('Uploaded file was not in the correct format\\n\\nExample of the correct format:\\nquestion1,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4\\n
   question2,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4\\nquestion3,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4')</script>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Quentin's answer, would switching the single and double quotes around also fix the issue?

Comment: Glad to have been a help, I actually just tried it and it didn't work for me! is that with double escaping as well?

Answer (score 0):

Put one space between \n and next character and it will work. I tried that for your code on my system and it worked